# API 404 using VueJs, ExpressJs and Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, api, express, mongoose, vue.js

So I am getting a 404 error when my app is trying to connect to my api

I have created an api which works fine, as all data is shown when I access 'http://localhost:3000/api/users'

However, when I access the data through my Vue app, I get a 404:

> GET http://localhost:8080/api/users 404 (Not Found)

Code below:

Server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var users = require('./routes/users.js'); //routes are defined here
var app = express(); //Create the Express app
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

var mongoUri = 'mongodb://foo';
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);

//configure body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use('/api', users); //This is our route middleware

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('listening to port ' + port)
});

module.exports = app;
```

Home.vue

```
<script>
    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
       data() {
           return {
               quote: ''
           }
       },
       created() {
           axios.get('/api/users')
               .then((res) => {
                   console.log(res.data);
                   this.quote = res.data;
               })
               .catch(error => {
                   console.log("error", error);
               });
       },
   }
</script>
```

Users.js

```
var Users = require('../models/users.js');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/users')
    // Get all users
    .get(function(req, res) {
        Users.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }

            res.json(users);
       });
    });
```

webpack.config.js

```
output: {
    path: __dirname + '/build/',
    publicPath: 'build/',
    filename: 'build.js'
},
```

What am I doing wrong. Can I assume its something to do with my server.js?

Comment: looks like you're accessing the wrong port `8080` instead of `3000`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like axios is making the request on port `8080`.

You can specify the correct port number in the `.get` method like so:

```
axios.get('/api/users', { port: 3000 }).then(...)
```

Comment: yeah the same error. Think it may have something to do with the webpack.config file?

Answer (score 0):

add in Server.js, you problem Cross-domain.
In place do not origin your url than accesses the vue.js

```
app.all('*', function (req, res, next) {
var origin = req.get('origin');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:8080');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type, Accept, Authorization');

if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    return res.status(200).end();
}
next();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Finally worked it out. I needed to add the below code to the webpack.config file:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api/*' : {
            target: 'http://localhost:3000'
        }
    }
}
```